# How to set marginLeft property using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I used the following code to set the left margin for a div with `id=""`

```
document.getElementById('s4-ca').style.marginLeft = '0px';
```

However getting an error like Object Required!

UPDATE - My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var groupName;
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    async: false,
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=Group]").each(function()
    {
    groupName = $(this).attr("Name");
    });
    }
    });
    if($.trim(groupName) != 'ABC')
    {
    document.getElementById('s4-leftpanel').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('s4-ca').style.marginLeft = '0px';
    }
</Script>
```

Comment: Sorry I was not knowing Jquery at all, i am using this for my Sharepoint 2010 master page !!I dont know what you meant by tagged JQuery!!

Comment: Your headline says "JQuery - How to set Margin left property", does it not?

Comment: @alex let me put full code . not sure with JQuery, First time using it!!

Comment: @alex Plz have a look at the code, I thought it is a jquery !! Plz suggest if not!!

Comment: @Emreerik can anyone tell me, my question is for jQuery or JavaScript, I thought I seen some JQquery functions, that's why I put

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your JavaScript, just give the `<div>` a matching `id` property, then it should work fine, i.e.

```
<div id="s4-ca"></div>
```

So there reason you're getting the error is because `document.getElementById('s4-ca')` doesn't find a en element with a matching `id`, so it's `null`, and you can't reference the `style` property on a null object.

Also, when you set the `marginLeft` there's no need to specify units for zero, you can use just `0`.

```
document.getElementById('s4-ca').style.marginLeft = "0";
```

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated question, Plz also suggest whether my question is for Jquery or javascript, Someone changed my heading and query to JavsScript!!

Answer (score 4):

Not reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/VH2z2/

I assume you call `document.getElementById` **before** the element is available.

Either include the code on the bottom of the page or in the `load` event handler, e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('s4-ca').style.marginLeft = '0px';
};
```

You should not do this if there is other JavaScript code which might set a `load` event handler (you would overwrite it).

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated code, Does't seem to be working!! I am doing it in a sharepoint master page!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this possibly?

```
$('#s4-ca').css({ marginLeft: 0 });
```

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated code, Does't seem to be working!! I am doing it in a sharepoint master page!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#s4-ca').css({ marginLeft: 0 });
```

or

```
$('#s4-ca').css('margin-left', 0 );
```

your code is not jquery, but the code above is the way to do this in jquery, both work.

update: your error message probably means that there is no element with id="s4-ca", please check for such an element! see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DzyW/ where your code just works.

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated code, Does't seem to be working!! I am doing it in a sharepoint master page!!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is "object requierd"
 that means that

```
document.getElementById('s4-ca')
```

returns nothing, you must make sure an element with id 's4-ca' exists

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated code,  I am doing it in a sharepoint master page!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery (according to your question's tag)

```
$("#s4-ca").css('marginLeft','0px');
```

[.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) Api of jQuery

Comment: Plz have a look at the updated code, Does't seem to be working!! I am doing it in a sharepoint master page!!